# How to make UITableViewCell display fullscreen (allow paging)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, scroll-paging

I have a custom **UITableView - Scroll, Paging Enable**. Because each of my cell has one background image, I want each time I scroll up or down it will display each image as full screen. I try to make my **UITableViewCell to be full screen** (stretch its height as big as the tableview).

However, I've got a problem: when I scroll(paging), the cell doesn't display as full screen. It contains a small part of the next cell. Then the part of next cell increase bigger and bigger each time I scroll(paging) down.

I didn't see any Auto Layout Option for UITableViewCell, cannot add constraint to the prototype cell. Would you please suggest me the way to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: If the cell comes from a .xib / storyboard that uses auto layout, it uses auto layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just add this two lines of code and it works for me

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

// ***** The following SWIFT function expands the cell image view to full screen (frame.size.height), adding to M.Salah's reply above.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```