# swipe between views (without xib)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, viewcontroller

I am trying to get an interface with 3 views. I want that I can swipe between those (like Snapchat etc.). I tried it with a `UIScrollView` but I found only solutions with `xib` files as `subviews`. Is there any way to get this swipe view with `storyboard` view controllers as `subviews`?
(I need a `TableViewController` as one `subview` and a `xib` file doesn't allow those views)

Comment: In storyboard you can do it using `UICollectionView`. I'm not sure how it looks in Snapchat though.

Comment: Aha, now I've seen you want to user TableViewController. I guess you'll have to user container view and put inside your table view controller.

Comment: and where do I put the container view in my storyboard?

Comment: You should put your view container in the cell of the collection view. Actually you'll probably want to have 3 cells, each four your specific view. But it's up to you. You could also use only one or two cells and reuse it - depends on your needs. If you haven't done it before you may want to search how to match the size to your screen. This may be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531413/how-to-make-uitableviewcell-display-fullscreen-allow-paging